# XCode automate build delivery that contain many files

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have big project that contain more than 1000 files. Everything is good if I build my project for release version, but at different steps of development I need to demonstrate separate features that may not contain all of these files.

So for example I have 1000 files - there are archive (levels) for my game. I need to build just my kernel without all these files and for example send a demo to a customer that demonstrate some features.

As a result, I save my time for building app and deliver to a customer.

For delivery my build to a customer I use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) and now my build using around 100 mb of space, but that I can demonstrate new features for a customer I can send just a build that contain all require files and whithout all 1000 levels (if I remove levels a build use just 10 mb of space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few choices:

1)  Duplicate your Release Scheme and create a new one, called "Demo" and have it include only the files needed.

2)  Add a post-action to your Release scheme.  Since post actions are shell scripts, they can be a arbitrarily complex.  For example, it could take your release build, make a copy of it, unzip it, delete the unneeded files, re-zip it, and upload it to your customer.